# Double pendulum find first integral

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, energy-conservation, potential-energy

Consider the following situation of a double pendulum in 2D.

[image: doppel pendulum]

We found the moving equations as
$$
\ddot{\theta_1}=-L_1\sin\theta_1 + \frac{m_2}{m_1}\cos\theta_2\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1),\\
\ddot{\theta}_2=-L_2\sin\theta_2.
$$
Respectively as a system (*)
$$
\dot{\theta}_1=w_1\\
\dot{\theta}_2=w_2\\
\dot{w}_1=-L_1\sin\theta_1+\frac{m_2}{m_1}\cos\theta_2\sin(\theta_2-\theta_1)\\
\dot{w}_2=-L_2\sin\theta_2.
$$

Now the task is to find a first integral of the system (*).
As a hint it is said to find formula for the kinetic and potential energy of the system by working in cartesian coordinates.

I am studying mathematics and not physics. So I do not know how to determine kinetic and potential energy. Can you help?

Comment: Kinetic energy is $1/2 m\vec{r}^2$ and see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potential_energy#Gravitational_potential_energy. But if you google double pendulum you will find hundreds of explanations.

Comment: You mean $1/2 m \vec{v}^2$